# How to use Worklight JMS adapter with WAS JMS jndi definitions

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I had posted a similar query with the Worklight JMS adapter but using WebSphere MQ JMS jndi definitions

In this case, I want to use the JMS jndi definitions created on the WAS ND application server layer that point to the WebSphere MQ queue manager

I have a Worklight 6.1 environment installed on a WAS ND application server profile. My requirement is to connect to an external WebSphere MQ JMS queue manager using the Worklight JMS adapter component

I have created the necessary JMS jndi definitions on the WAS ND application server profile - connecting to the MQ queue manager

Connection Factory = jms/WorklightMQCF
Queue Definition = jms/WorklightMQQueue

I'm unable to get the adapter to work when installed to the Worklight environment on the WAS ND server

The connection code in the adapter xml file is -

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="jms:JMSConnectionPolicyType">
        <jmsConnection
            connectionFactory="jms/WorklightMQCF"/>
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>
```

Not sure what is the correct syntax I need to enter in the adapter xml file.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I saw the other post you created where you mentioned that you did not want to use the 'file' option. Is there a problem with copying the .bindings file to the machine hosting the Worklight server? That route has worked for me:

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="jms:JMSConnectionPolicyType">

        <!-- Websphere MQ -->
        <namingConnection url="file:/Users/Nortey/Desktop/JMS/" initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>  

        <jmsConnection connectionFactory="CF4"/> 

    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="10"/>
</connectivity>
```

By copying the bindings file that was created by Websphere MQ to the machine hosting my Worklight server, I was able to make remote JMS calls (since the bindings file contained the IP address of my machine hosting Websphere MQ)

Comment: Well that route might work but it still ties you down to a particular WebSphere MQ queue manager.

Comment: I understand. For ApacheMQ, its trivial to accomplish what you're trying to do. But with WebsphereMQ, the only way I've accomplished this is by doing the above. If you do find an alternative, please do add a comment.

Comment: Well that route might work but it still ties you down to a particular WebSphere MQ queue manager. In my case, I want the JMS definitions to be hosted on the WAS layer (instead of on the MQ queue manager) as it will provide a layer of abstraction and better control to change the JNDI definitions at a later date to point to another queue manager without having to change the Worklight JMS adapter XML files. I just think having the JMS definitions on the WAS layer is much better and wanting a way to leverage this in the JMS adapter definition

Comment: Sure, will dig around a little more to find any alternatives